# LTS to LTS Upgrade

Tags: upgrade

Another question with this URL:

[How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

Has this:

> If you choose to upgrade before then, you can pass the -d option to
>   the upgrade tool, running do-release-upgrade -d or update-manager -d,
>   to upgrade from vanilla 10.04 to 12.04.

Am I correct in assuming that if I am actually running 10.04.4 (not vanilla?) that the above command line instructions would NOT work? I really do not mind waiting for the GUI Update Manager to show me the availability at 12.04.1 in July. I am just curious.

Answer (score 4):

[LTS usually has multiple point releases](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/whats-the-deal-with-point-releases-in-lts-versions) and 10.04.4 is just one of the point releases. In other words, 10.04.4 is indeed [Vanilla 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95785/what-is-vanilla-ubuntu).

So, your assumption that the commands won't work is wrong. They will work if you enter them correctly.

You can read about why the LTS to LTS upgrade is delayed until 12.04.1 in this question:

- [Upgrading LTS to LTS (server) -- why wait for the first point release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125825/upgrading-lts-to-lts-server-why-wait-for-the-first-point-release)

Answer (score 0):

based on my experience: Before starting a release upgrade you are asked to upgrade all your existing packages to their latest versions using the update manager. So if you were to do that step on 10.04, it would become 10.04.4 and also include the even newer updates.

So if you try to upgrade now, the upgrade should go through.

I suppose that the point behind waiting for the first point release is to ensure that teething issues get solved.

reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades

Comment: And I will not mind waiting for teething to finish. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer.